# Java memory: where are the references coming from?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, profiling, jmap

I have a Java program that is using a lot of memory.   I used jmap -histo:live to track down the objects that are using all the memory.  There are only a couple of types that are using up most of the memory,  there are > 1M of them,  but I can't tell where the references are coming *from*.

Is there any way to tell from the command line what types of objects are holding references to these?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have recursion?

Comment: Nope -- haven't seen it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to look at [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/), you can do a Heap Dump and then look at objects histogram and search for objects having reference to the "big" objects you're mentionning.